# Package importing in parts

Tags: javascript

I saw that sometimes when I import different modules from a package the size is different
For example

```
Import { ref } from 'vue' could be 100kb
And

Import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue' could be 600kb
```

I would like to do something similar for my package where I export different objects but the consumer does not have to import the entire package to get a single object out of the package

I'm using vite

Is there a name for this? And can you explain to me how it's done?

Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong but probably tree-shaking

Comment: I read about it a little and saw that tree shaking should automatically hapoen when using vite. But for my package when I import an independent object that weighs couple of kbs at most, the entire package is loaded 1.4MB

Comment: @123456 there are some caveats to writing code that is amenable to tree-shaking. If you're serious about writing JS libraries, it's worth looking in to. At the very least, make sure `sideEffects` is set to `false` in your `package.json` if that is in fact the case.

Comment: I added the sideeffects false property. And even  tried exporting just a small object but i still see 1.4mb when importing. Im using import cost extension btw - could it be an error with it?